# How to post to a webchat using direct line in Microsoft Bot Service?

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, azureportal, azure-bot-service

In the test web chat in azure portal, I get the bot to speak back to me the conversation id by getting it from session.message.address.conversation.id.

I wish to then view activities for this conversation id using the method described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-send-activity

(POST https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/abc123/activities
)

However, I get the following error:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "BadArgument",
    "message": "Unknown conversation"
    }
}
```

I have also tried:

POST https://webchat.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/9323c31ab1ba42328edc9191621f9c9c/activities

Any help on how I can use direct line to post/view activities for a webchat?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explain your issue**

I cannot reproduce your issue with `POST` conversations. Actually, I can only reproduce your issue with following step:

generate directline token => leverage the response `conversationId` and `token` directly call [Retrieve activities with HTTP GET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-receive-activities) with:

```
GET https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/abc123/activities
Authorization: Bearer token
```

The correct steps are:
generate token => `POST` to [Start a conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-start-conversation) => `GET` to [Retrieve activities with HTTP GET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-receive-activities).

**For your requirement**
I don't think we can interrupt outside of the conversion, as the description of [Generate a Direct Line token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication#generate-token)

> To generate a Direct Line token that can be used to access a single conversation.

So the token you asked from anywhere else, cannot request the activities in webchat.

**An work around**

You can leverage [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#easy-in-your-non-react-website-run-web-chat-inline) to quickly build up a web site bot testing environment. And generate the token in your own server for the bot client authentication. Then you can use the generated token and conversationId for requesting all the activites between bot and this bot client web site outside of the box.

Comment: I see. The issue I am having, is that I am starting the conversation in the webchat. And so this is the location of the conversation.

https://webchat.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/abc123/activities

Then I am trying to use direct line to post to this, but am unable to do so. Is there anyway I can connect to that conversation outside the webchat box? Perhaps by using channelData/channelActivitiesId?

Comment: I don't think we can achieve this. But as an workaround, you can store all the activities in a DB, as following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Bot-Framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-state-azure-cosmosdb, then you can query in this db for the activies outside the box.

Comment: Ok, when building the webchat website - would I be able to use the new token and convId to speak to it via directline? Or is this just a separate webchat from the one in azure portal?

Comment: Yes, a separate webchat from the one in azure portal.